# A functor to handle object by reference or pointer or iterator

Tags: c++

I want a function object that takes X as template parameter. Sometimes it's an object(/reference), sometimes it's a pointer to the object. Rarely it is a pointer to pointer to object. Is there some template magic I can do to just get p / *p / **p as many times as needed to get the object itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just layers of pointers, as simple template overload will do the trick. You can even encapsulate it in a CRTP mixin (although that would take a bit of metaprogramming, so I won't demonstrate here).

```
struct drill_ftor {
     foo operator() ( bar & x ) {}

     template< typename t >
     foo operator() ( t * x ) { return (*this)( * x ); }
};
```

The templated parameter `t *` matches `bar *`, `bar **`, `bar ****`, or whatever. It also matches `int *`, but that just leads to an error because there is no overload matching `operator() ( int )`.

Comment: Perfect! And I love the name drill!

Comment: Can you make a version that determines type foo automatically from the pointer type? Thanks.